# Spring Security authorization (for several new app and SSO for older apps)

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, server

Please point me to the right direction.

We are doing several Spring (Boot) apps. From user perspective they should look like one app with only one time login.

I guess there should be one separate app "Login server" that all other apps will direct to for authorization.

**What is correct terms for such case, what exactly I should be looking in docs, any examples?**

And as harder addon this login server should be later work well with legacy running apps, so it should not matter if user started working from older or newer app.